# Ubuntu : How to shutdown the system after 9 hours when it is started

Tags: 18.04, bash, cron, gnome-shell

1. How to shut down the system after 9 hours from the system switched on time?

   From the time system switched on to 9 hours it should be shut downed everyday...
2. How to notify the system by specific time using cron?

   ```
   20 14 * * * notify-send "Get your tea!"
   ```

   I have a line like that in `crontab` but nothing pops up.

Comment: Please have a look over it and answer to any of these context

Comment: @Jos updated, I just added as it is important

Comment: The command is `notify-send "Get your tea!"` , not `echo 'notify-send "Get your tea!"'`.

Comment: thank you 57 15 * * * notify-send "Get your tea!" but that doesn't work buddy

Comment: Works on my system. Are you using your user's crontab, or the root crontab?

Comment: That really make sense now am running user cron

Comment: Instead of shutdown and losing all your work, wouldn't locking screen at "tea time" be better?

Answer (score 5):

shutdown has an option for that:

```
shutdown -r +540
```

(9*60) but you will need to add it in minutes AND it does not survive a reboot.

The more useful method would be to use the `at` command (you will need to install it with `sudo apt install at`). Works like this:

```
echo "shutdown" > at now + 9 hours
```

have it execute in something like `/etc/rc.local`. This will survice a reboot but will add a 2nd shutdown when a reboot happens. You can list tasks set with `at` and even remove them.

cron does not understand 'now' so is not really the tool to use. But there was an addition made to cron where you can use @reboot. You can use the @reboot option and connect it to `shutdown -r +540`. That would be:

```
@reboot  /usr/sbin/shutdown -r +540
```

Mind that any method you use will kill any active process.

Comment: Thank you @Rinzwind please explain what's that rc.local and let me know if I can add the command in .sh and to execute it via cron will that make sense or suggest something like this